# Is there const in C?

Tags: c++, c, constants, language-comparisons

This question may be naive, but:

- is there `const` keyword in C?
- since which version?
- are there any semantic and/or syntactic differences between `const` in C and C++?

Comment: See Also: [Why do most C developers use define instead of const?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024318/why-do-most-c-developers-use-define-instead-of-const)

Comment: @C.Ross: That kind of sentences led me to ask the question :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162480/const-in-c

Comment: Probable dupe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308194/shall-i-prefer-constants-over-defines

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There are no syntactic differences between C and C++ with regard to `const` keyword, besides a rather obscure one: in C (since C99) you can declare function parameters as

```
void foo(int a[const]);
```

which is equivalent to

```
void foo(int *const a);
```

declaration. C++ does not support such syntax.

Semantic differences exist as well. As @Ben Voigt already noted, in C `const` declarations do not produce constant expressions, i.e. in C you can't use a `const int` object in a `case` label, as a bit-field width or as array size in a non-VLA array declaration (all this is possible in C++). Also, `const` objects have external linkage by default in C (internal linkage in C++).

There's at least one more semantic difference, which Ben did not mention. Const-correctness rules of C++ language support the following standard conversion

```
int **pp = 0;
const int *const *cpp = pp; // OK in C++

int ***ppp = 0;
int *const *const *cppp = ppp; // OK in C++
```

These initializations are illegal in C.

```
int **pp = 0;
const int *const *cpp = pp; /* ERROR in C */

int ***ppp = 0;
int *const *const *cppp = ppp; /* ERROR in C */
```

Generally, when dealing with multi-level pointers, C++ says that you can add const-qualification at any depth of indirection, as long as you also add const-qualification all the way to the top level.

In C you can only add const-qualification to the type pointed by the top-level pointer, but no deeper.

```
int **pp = 0;
int *const *cpp = pp; /* OK in C */

int ***ppp = 0;
int **const *cppp = ppp; /* OK in C */
```

Another manifestation of the same underlying general principle is the way const-correctness rules work with arrays in C and C++. In C++ you can do

```
int a[10];
const int (*p)[10] = &a; // OK in C++
```

Trying to do the same in C will result in an error

```
int a[10];
const int (*p)[10] = &a; /* ERROR in C */
```

Comment: +1 Did not know this specifics of the difference between C and C++

Answer (score 15):

The first two questions are answered here: [Const in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162480/const-in-c)

Yes there are quite a few differences in semantics between `const` in C and C++.

- In C++, `const` variables of appropriate type are *integral constant expressions* (if their initializers are compile-time constant expressions) and can be used in context which requires that, such as array bounds, and in enum definitions.  In C, they are not and cannot be.
- In C++, `const` global variables automatically have `static` linkage, so you can put them in header files.  In C, such variables have external linkage and that would generate duplicate definition errors at link time.

Comment: And these differences are... ? :)

Comment: @Armen: Patience, padawan, patience.

Comment: I see we meet again Mr Bond ... or shall I say Mr Voight?. You used to answer my questions on comp.lang.c++ waaay, back in the day :)

Comment: "In C++, const variables of appropriate type are integral constant expressions" - they can be, but they aren't in all cases. I guess that is the main reason for adding consexpr keyword to ISOC++11. Example: int i=0; std::cin>>i; const int I=i; int is[I]; The last command is illegal according to the standard, because I is not a static expression, however it is a constant variable. So a more correct statement would be: "In C++, const variables of appropriate type CAN BE integral constant expressions, but in C they can be never".

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is a `const` keyword.  It was added as part of the 1989 standard.

As far as compatibility, here's a paragraph from Harbison & Steele, 5th edition:

> A top-level declaration that has the type qualifier `const` but no explicit storage class is considered to be `static` in C++ but `extern` in C.  To remain compatible, examine top-level `const` declarations and provide an explicit storage class.  
>
> In C++, string constants are implicitly `const`; they are not in C.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `const` has been there since at least since ANSI C (aka C89).

It certainly appears in my copy of ["The C Programming Language (2nd Edition)", Kernighan & Ritchie](http://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Programming-Language-2nd/dp/0131103628/) (published in 1988).

Relevant extract:

> The `const` and `volatile` properties are new with the ANSI standard. The purpose of `const` is to
>   announce objects that may be placed in read-only memory, and perhaps to increase opportunities for
>   optimization.

Comment: [ANSI C is not only C89](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C).

Comment: @PeterMortensen: yeah perhaps I should have said "since **first** ANSI C (aka C89)" but as noted in that Wikipedia article "Historically, the names [ANSI C] referred specifically to the original and best-supported version of the standard (known as C89 or C90)."  and "This version [C89] of the language is often referred to as ANSI C"

Answer (score 5):

Two other differences:

- `const arraytype` (i.e `typedef int A[1]; const A a = { 0 };`) specifies a constant array type ( http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#112 and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1059 ) (and whose elements are so-qualified too) in C++, but a [non-constant array type](http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/const-and-arrays/) whose elements are so-qualified in C.
- `const const` is valid in C99 (not valid in C89), not valid in C++ in any version (you can only semantically repeat a `const`, not syntactically). It contracts to `const` in C99.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. `const` is there in C, from C89.

Here is a good read is about [behaviour of const keyword in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417388/c-behaviour-of-the-const-keyword).

Comment: C89, actually (or C90, whatever it's actually called).

Answer (score 2):

The semantic in C is different than in C++. For example,

```
unsigned const a = 10;
unsigned A[a];
```

in file scope would be valid in C++, but not in C.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a `const` keyword in C. It's been there since C90.

Syntactically, it can occur in the same places as in C++. Semantically, it's a bit more lax, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

According to [ESR](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/c_evolution.html), `const` was added in the ANSI C Draft Proposed Standard.  [Eric Giguere's summary of ANSI C](http://www.ericgiguere.com/articles/ansi-c-summary.html), dated 1987, confirms it.

[This looks like the draft itself](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt) -- search for "3.5.3 Type qualifiers".

Answer (score 1):

There is a "const" keyword in C, and it has been for a *long* time.  If a variable is designated "const", writes to it are forbidden.

Additionally, in some environments, variables declared "const" may be located in a different data segment from other variables.  This data segment may offer hardware write protection, and for embedded systems, may be stored in ROM or flash memory rather than in RAM (a very important distinction on some processors which have a lot more ROM or flash than RAM--e.g. 128 KB flash and 3.5 KB RAM, or 2 KB ROM and 96 bytes RAM).

Note that the compiler will generally *not* make any inferences about "const" values or expressions involving them.  If I say "const char foo[] = "Hello";" and then later make reference to foo[1], the compiler will load the value (which will most likely be 'e') from wherever foo[] is stored and use the loaded value.  Sometimes this usefully allows values to be patched in a compiled code image, but sometimes it just wastes code.

If you want to define a number to to be a compile-time "substitutable" constant, the best way, at least for integer constants, may be to use "enum".  For example, "enum {woozle=19;}" will cause 19 to be substituted for "woozle" throughout the code.  Note that unlike textual substitutions; enum declarations obey proper rules of scope.