# C++11 constexpr function's argument passed in template argument

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, metaprogramming, constexpr

This used to work some weeks ago:

```
template <typename T, T t>
T            tfunc()
{
    return t + 10;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr T       func(T t)
{
    return tfunc<T, t>();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << func(10) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But now `g++ -std=c++0x` says:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘constexpr T func(T) [with T = int]’:
main.cpp:29:25:   instantiated from here
main.cpp:24:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘tfunc()’
main.cpp:24:24: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:16:14: note: template<class T, T t> T tfunc()
main.cpp:25:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

`clang++ -std=c++11` says that template's parameters of `tfunc<T, t>()` are ignored because invalid.

Is that a bug, or a fix ?

PS:

`g++ --version` => `g++ (GCC) 4.6.2 20120120 (prerelease)`

`clang++ --version` => `clang version 3.0 (tags/RELEASE_30/final)` (3.0.1)

Comment: FWIW, Clang 3.1 HEAD also spews the same errors.

Answer (score 10):

The parameter `t` is not a constant expression. Hence the error. It should be also noted that it cannot be a constant expression.

You can pass the constant expression as argument, but inside the function, the object (the parameter) which holds the value, is not a constant expression.

Since `t` is not a constant expression, it cannot be used as template argument:

```
return tfunc<T, t>(); //the second argument must be a constant expression
```

---

Maybe, you want something like this:

```
template <typename T, T t>
T  tfunc()
{
    return t + 10;
}

template <typename T, T t>  //<---- t became template argument!
constexpr T  func()
{
    return tfunc<T, t>();
}

#define FUNC(a)  func<decltype(a),a>()

int main()
{
    std::cout << FUNC(10) << std::endl;
}
```

Now it should work : [online demo](http://ideone.com/7DKFM)

Comment: I am still confused by the sentence : *an argument to a function cannot be a const expression*

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: That is why I explained that part in the next para. Did you read it?

Comment: you mean `..func(T t)` inside `func` , `t` in not constexp , right?

Comment: That's not true. `10` is actually a constant expression.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I know that is a const expression. And I also know that you didn't read the second para in my post.

Comment: lol "And I also know that you didn't read the second para in my post."

Comment: @Nawaz I don't need to read a correct second part if I want to complain about the wrong first part, do I?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I think, sometimes some sentences can be interpreted in many different ways, that is why authors write few more sentences to explain that part which seems confusing (or even wrong). I know that some other author (or even the same author) can re-write the whole thing, making things clear from the first line.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: No. There is a difference between *readonly* expression and *constant* expression. If you write `f(const T t)`, then `t` is *readonly* expression.

Comment: I know my code has worked some weeks ago, I just simplify it for the example. A `constexpr` function is evaluated at compile-time, so I don't know why now (seems to be with a new version of gcc), it can't resolve `tfunc<T, t>`

Comment: @Gravemind because a constexpr function is a *function*. The function behind this still is a normal function. That this fails has nothing to do with `constexpr`, but just with the normal rule that function parameters cannot be used as template arguments.

Comment: Ok, I missed the fact that `constexpr` functions are just simple functions that can be evaluated at compile-time. But, why g++ force the evaluation as in a run-time context even if g++ knows that `func(10)` can be evaluated at compile-time (it can also explain why before it works perfectly).

Comment: The parameter may be a constant-expression (indirectly). Consider `template <typename T>
constexpr T       func(T t)
{
    return t+t;
}`
 Here, the compiler knows how to implement `+` both at compile-time and at run-time, and hence this code is valid and is suitable for compile-time execution. So, parameters to a `constexpr` function are a bit schizophrenic - sometimes they are constant-expressions, sometimes they are not.

Comment: @Gravemind, if you intend that the parameter to func will *only* be used in a compile-time context, then func should take a template int parameter. By using `constexpr` and simple parameters, you are requesting that the function be compiled/compilable in both contexts, run-time and compile-time. (That's my intuition at the moment anyway.)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: In other words, (according to you), this should work : http://ideone.com/xILLF  ... but it doesn't.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid : the puprose of my code is to use the type inference of `func(10)` (here: int) to call the template function `tfunc` that take a generic type/value as template parameter.

Comment: @Nawaz : I've already used `decltype` in a define, but it's awful and I want to stay in c++11 meta-programming only.

Comment: @Nawaz, that example works on g++-4.6. And I think that's the correct behaviour, and that ideone is out-of-date. But I might be wrong.

Comment: So, what do I do ? do I downgrade to g++-4.6 or hope that was a regression and wait for a fix ?

Comment: @Gravemind, I don't think you need to downgrade (I'm not sure I understand why you suggested you might downgrade!). Ultimately, not all `constexpr` are constant-expressions. There are two solutions to the original problem - either upgrade the func parameter to a full constant-expression (i.e Nawaz's solution in this answer), *or* to downgrade the parameter that is accepted by the `tfunc::tfunc` constructor from a template-paremeter to a mere `constexpr`.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid, I want to downgrade because this works on g++-4.6. The only point to do that, is to have a simple syntax for calling a template function (`tfunc`) with a generic static value template parameter (`T t`). Yes, I can do `tfunc<int, 10>()` or `tfunc< a_type_long_as_hell, my_simple_value >()`, but it's going to be unreadable very quick inside the rest of my code (and I don't want to obfuscate my code with macros). So, I'm still looking for a way to have at the beginning `indirect_func(simple_value)` (with 1 parameter) and at the end a call of `template <typename T, T t> void tfunc()`.

Comment: @Gravemind, do you have any helpful bounds on `T` and `t`? For example, if they were guaranteed to be `int` between `0` and `10`, then you could easily write `func` with a `switch` statement. In order to make `func` into a `constexpr` you would need to replace the switch with something like `return t==0 ? tfunc<T,0>() : t==1 ? tfunc<T,1>() ? t==2 ? tfunc<T,2>() : ` ... and so on.

Comment: @Gravemind, I've added another answer here to directly tackle your goal - although it has other problems.

Comment: you said in previous comments : "There is a difference between readonly expression and constant expression. If you write f(const T t), then t is readonly expression" . Can you please link to some articles which explains about all this in deep? , Thanks

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: You can read [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248571/is-there-const-in-c). If still not satisfied, then create a new topic, and quote my statement there, and ask for detail explanation. I'm sure many good answers you will get.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid, In fact, if you want to know what I am doing with all that, this is for a simple implementation of [impossibly fast delegates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11015/The-Impossibly-Fast-C-Delegates). So, `func` is used like this `bind(&A::method)` and (in g++-4.6) it calls `_bindMethod<void(A::*)(int), &A::method>()` (for example), then I use it to create my fast delegate. But, since g++-4.6.2, according to the [c++11 constexpr standart](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2235.pdf), this doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Gravemind, that blog piece is very interesting. But I must admit I don't see the connection directly. Are you essentially saying that you are unable to change the signatures of `func` or `tfunc`, but you still wish them to be able to call each other? i.e. `func` must have the same signature because it's going to be used in that delegate?

Comment: @Gravemind, .... perhaps you want to be able to take the address of the templated function, much like was done in the blog post you linked to? Like `&tfunc<T, t>` ?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid, exactly, and use `func(&A::f)` to simplify and generalize the syntax by using type inference of template functions. But now, I know it uses a bug of g++-4.6: in a static context (`func(10)` or `func(&A::f)`), my `constexpr func` is consider totally static (statements, return, and arguments). `func` was a meta-programming function but strongly typed (really nice concept by the way). So I haven't completely understood c++11 constexpr. So, now I use a macro as ugly as it is.

Comment: @Aaron parameters of constexpr functions are never constant expressions. Any time you call a constexpr function within a constant expression, function invocation substitution is done. Any parameter names used in the `return` statement are then replaced by the argument expression. So no parameters are used, but the arguments are used directly.

Answer (score 2):

I get the feeling that `constexpr` must also be valid in a 'runtime' context, not just at compile-time. Marking a function as `constexpr` encourages the compiler to try to evaluate it at compile-time, but the function must still have a valid run-time implementation.

In practice, this means that the compiler doesn't know how to implement this function at runtime:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T       func(T t)
{
    return tfunc<T, t>();
}
```

A workaround is to change the constructor such that it takes its `t` parameter as a normal parameter, not as a template parameter, and mark the constructor as `constexpr`:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T       tfunc(T t)
{
    return t + 10;
}
template <typename T>
constexpr T       func(T t)
{
    return tfunc<T>(t);
}
```

There are three levels of 'constant-expression-ness':

1. template int parameter, or (non-VLA) array size     // Something that *must* be a constant-expression
2. `constexpr`                // Something that *may* be a constant-expression
3. non-constant-expression

You can't really convert items that are low in that list into something that is high in that list, but obviously the other route it possible.

For example, a call to this function

```
constexpr int foo(int x) { return x+1; }
```

isn't necessarily a constant-expression.

```
// g++-4.6 used in these few lines. ideone doesn't like this code. I don't know why
int array[foo(3)]; // this is OK
int c = getchar();
int array[foo(c)]; // this will not compile (without VLAs)
```

So the return value from a `constexpr` function is a constant expression *only if* all the parameters, and the implementation of the function, can be completed at executed at compile-time.

Comment: `constexpr int i = something_that_MUST_be_a_constexpr;`

Comment: @Xeo, it must *at least* be a `constexpr`. Whereas `template<int t> struct X; X<i> x;` requires that `i` be even more than a `constexpr`.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have used the second `constexpr` as a short-hand for `constant expression`... :) I just wanted to say that for `constexpr`, sometimes something *must* be a constant expression - when a variable is declared as such. (As an answer to your "`constexpr` // Something that *may* be a constant-expression".)

Comment: This example shows exactly why I don't understand why my code doesn't work: `foo(3)` and `foo(c)` are 2 totally different interpretations by g++. `foo(3)` will be evaluated at compile-time, and `foo(c)` will generate the code to do it at run-time. So, why `foo(3)` is evaluated as a run-time function ?

Comment: @Xeo, I agree that "*may*" is a bad choice of word. I'll think further about how to edit that, and you can feel free to edit it yourself. There is a certain 'split-personality' around `constexpr`. A `constexpr` only graduates to be a full 'constant-expression' if certain conditions hold. I'm sure you understand that already, the challenge is to summarize this for the layman. [ And I'm no expert, hence I'm furiously testing all this on various compilers - where each compiler is behaving a little differently :-) ]

Answer (score 2):

Recap the question: You have two functions which take a parameter of type `T`. One takes its parameter as a template parameter, and the other as a 'normal' parameter.
I'm going to call the two functions `funcT` and `funcN` instead of `tfunc` and `func`.
You wish to be able to call `funcT` from `funcN`. Marking the latter as a `constexpr` doesn't help.

Any function marked as `constexpr` must be compilable as if the `constexpr` wasn't there. `constexpr` functions are a little schizophrenic. They only graduate to full constant-expressions in certain circumstances.

It would not be possible to implement funcN to run at runtime in a simple way, as it would need to be able to work for *all* possible values of *t*. This would require the compiler to instantiate many instances of `tfunc`, one for each value of t. But you can work around this if you're willing to live with a small subset of T. There is a template-recursion limit of 1024 in g++, so you can easily handle 1024 values of T with this code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
#include<array>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, T t>
constexpr T funcT() {
        return t + 10;
}

template<typename T, T u>
constexpr T worker (T t) {
        return t==0 ? funcT<T,u>() : worker<T, u+1>(t-1);

}
template<>
constexpr int worker<int,1000> (int ) {
            return -1;
}


template <typename T>
constexpr T       funcN(T t)
{
        return t<1000 ? worker<T,0>(t) : -1;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << funcN(10) << std::endl;
    array<int, funcN(10)> a; // to verify that funcN(10) returns a constant-expression
    return 0;
}
```

It uses a function `worker` which will recursively convert the 'normal' parameter `t` into a template parameter `u`, which it then uses to instantiate and execute `tfunc<T,u>`.

The crucial line is `return funcT<T,u>() : worker<T, u+1>(t-1);`

This has limitations. If you want to use `long`, or other integral types, you'll have to add another specialization. Obviously, this code only works for t between 0 and 1000 - the exact upper limit is probably compiler-dependent. Another option might be to use a binary search of sorts, with a different worker function for each power of 2:

```
template<typename T, T u>
constexpr T worker4096 (T t) {
        return t>=4096 ? worker2048<T, u+4096>(t-4096) : worker2048<T, u>(t);

}
```

I think this will work around the template-recursion-limit, but it will still require a very large number of instantiations and would make compilation *very* slow, if it works at all.

Comment: you can verify a `constexpr` function by declaring an `constexpr auto` or the specific `return type` in the main(since c++17). Basically `constexpr auto var = funcN(10)`. If it works, it's constexpr.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it should give an error - it has no way of knowing that you passed in a constant value as t to func.

More generally, you can't use runtime values as template arguments. Templates are inherently a compile-time construct.

Comment: And `constexpr` functions can be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @Xeo I don't see the relevance of your comment to this answer. It sounds like, I say "My hand cannot be used to walk around." and you say "And your arm can be used to move your hand."

Comment: @Johannes: Well, since `constexpr` functions can be evaluated at compile time, their arguments may to be known at compile-time, and as such they *could* be used as template arguments - if we could specify that we *only* allow compile-time values as arguments. Sadly, `constexpr void f(constexpr int x);` doesn't work. I know that you could just say `template<int x> constexpr void f();` at that point, but still... Template arguments are not subject to conversions, for example.

Comment: @Xeo it seems you should have put these excellent comments as comments to the question.