# Assigning pointers to pointers with or without qualifiers

Tags: c++, c, pointers, c99

While this compiles:

```
char* p2c;
const char* p2cc = p2c; //fine
```

because lhs pointed type has all the qualifiers of rhs pointed type, this does not:

```
char** p2p2c;
const char** p2p2cc = p2p2c; //fail
```

but this does:

```
const char * const * p2cp2cc = p2p2c; //fine
```

Why exactly does this happen?

Comment: The last example will only compile in C++, but not in C.

Comment: That's just the way it is in C and C++. These are two different languages with different const-correctness rules. In C++ `T **` is convertible to `const T* const *`. In C `T **` is convertible to `T* const *`, but not to `T* const *`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5249001/187690

Comment: @AndreyT your example lists same type in opposite meanings ;d (`T* const *`)

Comment: Oh... A copy-paste error. I meant to say "In C `T **` is convertible to `T* const *`, but not to `const T* const *`.

Comment: I'll quote a part of your answer that I find particularly concise: *C++ says that you can add const-qualification at any depth of indirection, as long as you also add const-qualification all the way to the top level.

In C you can only add const-qualification to the type pointed by the top-level pointer, but no deeper.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This does not work:

```
char** p2p2c;
const char** p2p2cc = p2p2c; //fail
```

If that was allowed you would be allowed to break const-correctness:

```
const int k = 10;
int *p;
int **pp = &p;
int const **kpp = pp;     // Should this be allowed, if so:
*kpp = &k;                // fine, kpp promises not to change it
                          // yet this does p = &k;
                          // p made no such promise! this is a hidden const_cast!
*p = 5;
```

If the assignment was allowed, you would enable setting a non-const pointer (intermediate) to refer to a constant value, possibly causing undefined behavior in a non-obvious to see way. By disallowing that operation the type system is safer.

> but this does:

```
const char * const * p2cp2cc = p2p2c; //fine
```

This is fine, since the intermediate pointer is fixed, it is impossible to reset the intermediate pointer to refer to a const object and break const-correctness

Comment: Why can one safely convert `char**` to `char const * const *` ?

Comment: @elmes: because the intermediate pointer being also `const` means that you cannot reset it to the *wrong* object.

Comment: Seems quite reasonable now, thanks.

Comment: Again, implicit conversion from `char**` to `char const * const *` is only available in C++, but not in C.

Comment: @AndreyT: I was not aware, and did not even read the tags (my bad, as I filter C++ only, I tend to ignore the tags although I should not)

Answer (score -1):

[**cdecl**](http://cdecl.org/) really helps in cases like this.

```
const char** p2p2cc = declare p2p2cc as pointer to pointer to const char
```

and

```
const char * const * p2cp2cc = declare p2cp2cc as pointer to const pointer to const char
```

As you can see, the second version has the inner AND the outer pointer const, meaning it cannot modify either. The first version has the INNER pointer const and the outer non-const thereby breaking constnes.

On the other hand, this works:

```
char** const p = p2p2c;
```