# Sending "char**" into "const char**" function parameter

Tags: c

Suppose I have a function signature:

```
bool func(const char** arrayOfStrings);
```

And I have a auxiliary function with signature:

```
char** auxFunc(not relevant);
```

For some reason I can manage to do the following:

```
func(auxFunc(not relevant));
```

I got compiler warnings/errors:

error: initializing 'const char **' with an expression of type 'char **' discards qualifiers in nested pointer types

Why this is not working as I expect it to, and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking the compiler to perform an implicit conversion from `char **` to `const char **`, which dangerously violates the rules of const-correctness. This is why you get an error from the compiler.

Read the FAQ entry [here](http://parashift.com/c++-faq/constptrptr-conversion.html) to better understand the issue (there are numerous answers about that issue here on SO as well).

After that you should decide what's the best solution in your case: either redesign the code to eliminate the problem or suppress the error with an explicit cast. Nobody can do it for you without understanding your design/code in much greater detail (which you did not provide).

Comment: Maybe better to link to the [C FAQ entry](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html) for a C question.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, C does not make an implicit cast from `char **` to `char const **` although this would be safe.  You will have to cast it explicitly `func((char const **)(auxFunc()))`.

Comment: Safe? Absolutely not. `char **` is not implicitly convertible to `char const **` neither in C nor in C++. The conversion is unsafe, which is well explained in the FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/constptrptr-conversion.html