# Why aren't the argv and envp arguments to execve pointers to const?

Tags: process, c, posix

Take e.g. execve(2), which according to posix has this prototype [1]:

```
int execve(const char *path, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

To me, it seems as if

```
int execve(const char *path, const char *const argv[], const char *const envp[]);
```

would have been an obvious improvement.

So, does anyone know why this is as it is? What can explain the need
to possibly manipulate the given argv/envp strings?

[1] http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html

Comment: [In response to your comments on my deleted answer] Oh, I see what you mean — yes, my answer addresses the arguments of `main`, not the arguments of `argv`. That's really a C API question, not a Unix system design question. I think the answer is simply historical compatibility with the original, pre-const APIs.

Comment: Since questions about the C API (as opposed to general system design) are off-topic here, I'm voting to migrate to [so]. (Do not repost, the question will be moved soon.)

Comment: Presumably some programs mutate these buffers

Comment: That buffer may indeed be mutated in the new process but that would be on the other side of the exec, with a new memory layout which has nothing to do with the process sending off those arguments to the kernel before the exec happens.

Comment: Just stumbled over the same thing when looking at posix_spawn.
chainging the api to const char ** or const char * const * shouldn't even break existing implementations. To use these methods with the given signature I either have to copy the argv and envp arrays or just cast them and hope nothing goes wrong... Too bad!

Answer (score 2):

The `argv` and `envp` arguments to `execve()` are not pointers to `const` in order to preserve backwards compatibility with valid C code that was written before `const` was added to C.

C first appeared [in 1972](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_programming_language).  Later on, `const` was added to C [in 1987.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5248702)

In order to maintain compatibility with pre-`const` code, the updated-with-`const` declaration of `execve()` must be able to accept non-`const` inputs.  C does not allow assignments from `char *[]` to `const char *[]`.  This can be verified by trying (and failing) to compile the following program:

```
void  foo  ( const char * argv[] )  {  return;  }
void  main  ( int argc, char * argv[] )  {  foo ( argv );  }
```

Therefore, `char *const[]` is the strictest type that is backwards compatible with pre-`const` code.

The question provides a link to the POSIX documentation for `execve()`.  The linked POSIX documentation does explain this as follows:

> The statement about `argv[]` and `envp[]` being constants is included to
>   make explicit to future writers of language bindings that these
>   objects are completely constant. Due to a limitation of the ISO C
>   standard, it is not possible to state that idea in standard C. ...

Actually, to be precise: it is not possible to state that idea *in a way that is backwards compatible with pre-`const` code*.

> ... Specifying two levels of *`const`- qualification* for the `argv[]` and
>   `envp[]` parameters for the *exec* functions may seem to be the natural
>   choice, given that these functions do not modify either the array of
>   pointers or the characters to which the function points, but this
>   would disallow existing correct code. Instead, only the array of
>   pointers is noted as constant. The table of assignment compatibility
>   for *dst= src* derived from the ISO C standard summarizes the
>   compatibility:
>
> ```
>         dst:          char *[]   const char *[]   char *const[]   const char *const[]
> src:
> char *[]               VALID           -              VALID               -
> const char *[]           -           VALID              -               VALID 
> char * const []          -             -              VALID               - 
> const char *const[]      -             -                -               VALID
> ```
>
> Since all existing code ...

Meaning all code that existed prior to `const` being added to C.

> ... has a source type matching the first row, the
>   column that gives the most valid combinations is the third column. The
>   only other possibility is the fourth column, but using it would
>   require a cast on the `argv` or `envp` arguments. It is unfortunate that
>   the fourth column cannot be used, because the declaration a non-expert
>   would naturally use would be that in the second row.

Sources: [2018 edition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html), [2004 edition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is basically due to the hole in the C standard that prevents the implicit conversion from `T **` to `const T * const *`.  Such a conversion would be safe (a conversion from `T**` to `const T **` would be problematic), but the standard has not been updated to allow it.

mpb quotes from the POSIX standard

> The statement about argv[] and envp[] being constants is included to make explicit to future writers of language bindings that these objects are completely constant. Due to a limitation of the ISO C standard, it is not possible to state that idea in standard C.

which implies that the POSIX standard will be changed when/if the C standard is ever updated.

Answer (score -2):

Some programs manipulate the argv strings so that `ps` output show some state information. For example:

```
root      6550 10809  0 13:10 ?        00:00:00 pure-ftpd (IDLE)
root     32216     1  0 Apr05 ?        00:00:00 vtund[s]: waiting for connections on port 5000
1023     30448  9847  0 09:01 ?        00:00:01 imap [username 192.168.1.135]
```

Hence the argv values are not constant and should not be declared as such.

Comment: Presumably, however, those programs modify the copy of the argv strings in their *own* address space, not the address space of the process which called `execve`.